# Rails: ¿Cómo validar parametros de formulario en controlador?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Tengo el siguiente formulario:

```
<%= form_for :user, :url => { :action => :update, :controller => :usuario, :id => current_user.id }, :method => :put do |f| %>
        Nueva encuesta:
        <div style="padding-bottom: 11px;">
            <div class="field">
                <%= f.label :servicio %><br />
                 <%= f.check_box :fluido, {}, "fluido", false%>Servicio de fluidos<br />
                <%= f.check_box :solido, {}, "solido", false %>Servicio de control de sólidos<br />
                <%= f.check_box :ambiente, {}, "ambiente", false %>Servicio Ambiental<br />
              </div>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">
                 <%= f.submit %>
        </button>
    </div>
```

y quiero validar el valor de los checkbox para realizar ciertas acciones dentro del controlador, por ejemplo:

usuario_controller.rb:

```
@usuario = User.find(params[:id])
        if (request[:fluido]=='fluido')
            if @usuario.update_attributes(:fluido => 'fluido')
            redirect_to 'index'
            end
        end
        if (request[:solido]=='solido')
            if @usuario.update_attributes(:solido => 'solido')
            redirect_to 'index'
            end
        end
        if (request[:ambiente]=='ambiente')
            if @usuario.update_attributes(:ambiente => 'ambiente')
            redirect_to 'index'
            end
        end
```

el problema es que los valores del objeto request que se están comparando en los if, son 'nil', es decir no están devolviendo los valores del formulario

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La manera correcta de llamar a los parámetros es con `params`, no `request`, por tanto tu código debería quedar algo como:

```
@usuario = User.find(params[:id])
if params[:fluido] == 'fluido'
  if @usuario.update_attributes(:fluido => 'fluido')
    redirect_to 'index'
  end
end
if params[:solido] == 'solido'
  if @usuario.update_attributes(:solido => 'solido')
    redirect_to 'index'
  end
end
if params[:ambiente] == 'ambiente'
  if @usuario.update_attributes(:ambiente => 'ambiente')
    redirect_to 'index'
  end
end
```

Comentarios aparte:

- Veo un error en tu código. Cuando se deselecciona un valor en el checkbox, basado en las condiciones `if` que tienes, este no va a ser actualizado al llamar al submit. En general, creo que simplificarías mucho más tu código si usaras [strong parameters](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#strong-parameters), donde definirías qué parámetros son permitidos o no, además que solucionarías ese potencial bug que te comento.

```
def update
  @usuario = User.find(params[:id])
  redirect_to 'index' if @usuario.update(usuario_params)
end

private

def usuario_params
  params.require(:usuario).permit(:fluido, :solido, :ambiente)
end
```

- No conozco del todo la lógica de tu app, pero creo que lo adecuado sería guardar esos campos como booleanos en vez de string. Por ejemplo, el campo `fluido` denota si es fluido o no, igual con `solido`, etc. Además de esa forma no necesitarías redefinir los valores true/false de tu checkbox:

```
<%= f.check_box :fluido %>Servicio de fluidos<br />
<%= f.check_box :solido %>Servicio de control de sólidos<br />
<%= f.check_box :ambiente %>Servicio Ambiental<br />
```